# Redirecting to another path instead of given in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-router

App routes:

```
[
    { path: '', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' },
    { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule' },
    { path: 'error', loadChildren: './server-error/server-error.module#ServerErrorModule' },
    { path: 'access-denied', loadChildren: './access-denied/access-denied.module#AccessDeniedModule' },
    { path: 'not-found', loadChildren: './not-found/not-found.module#NotFoundModule' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found' }
]
```

LayoutModule Routes:

```
   [{
        path: '',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard' },
            { path: 'allcookies' , loadChildren: './allcookies/allcookies.module#AllcookiesModule' },
            { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
            { path: 'details', loadChildren: './details/details.module#DetailsModule' },
            { path: 'domains', loadChildren: './domains/domains.module#DomainsModule' },
        ]
    }]
```

I have DetailsModule routes coniguration like this,

```
[
  { path : '' , redirectTo: 'email-details' },
  { path : 'email-details' , component : EmailDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'email-details/:email_id' , component : EmailDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'email-details/:email_id/:curr_page' , component : EmailDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'fingerprint-details/:fp_id/:fp_page/domains/:user_id/:domain_page' , component : FingerprintDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'fingerprint-details/:fp_id/:fp_page/domains/:user_id' , component : FingerprintDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'fingerprint-details/:fp_id/:fp_page' , component : FingerprintDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'fingerprint-details/:fp_id' , component : FingerprintDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'fingerprint-details' , component : FingerprintDetailsComponent }
]
```

I have given url

> http://localhost:4302/details/fingerprint-details

But it os redirecting to

> http://localhost:4302/details/email-details/fingerprint-details

Comment: None of the routes shown above start with `details`. Are these the only routes in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the redirectTo property, you should write the absolute path from the route level.
I also always use `pathMatch: 'full'` in all of my routes to be sure I will not have relative path involved.

Test it with that configuration:

```
[
  { path : '' , redirectTo: '/email-details', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path : 'email-details' , pathMatch: 'full', component : EmailDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'email-details/:email_id' , pathMatch: 'full', component : EmailDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'email-details/:email_id/:curr_page' , pathMatch: 'full', component : EmailDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'fingerprint-details/:fp_id/:fp_page/domains/:user_id/:domain_page' , pathMatch: 'full', component : FingerprintDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'fingerprint-details/:fp_id/:fp_page/domains/:user_id' , pathMatch: 'full', component : FingerprintDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'fingerprint-details/:fp_id/:fp_page' , pathMatch: 'full', component : FingerprintDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'fingerprint-details/:fp_id', pathMatch: 'full', component : FingerprintDetailsComponent },
  { path : 'fingerprint-details' , pathMatch: 'full', component : FingerprintDetailsComponent }
]
```

Here's the corresponding link to the doc: 
https://angular.io/guide/router#redirecting-routes

Answer (score 0):

Quentin beat me to it.

https://angular.io/guide/router

> "A redirect route requires a pathMatch property to tell the router how
>   to match a URL to the path of a route. The router throws an error if
>   you don't."